# Show form per shortcode

Tags: shortcode

This is my code. I want to show it per shortcode.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id );
echo "Current Balance: ".$balance."<br><br>";
if ($_POST && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['amount'])){
    $towithdraw = $_POST['amount'];
        $towithdraws = "-".$towithdraw;
        if ($towithdraw > $balance){
            echo "Insufficient Funds!";
    }else{
        mycred_subtract( 'Withdrawal', $user_id, $towithdraws, 'Activity earnings withdrawal' );

        $uname = $_POST['uname'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $acct = $_POST['acct'];
        $link = $_POST['link'];
$name = $fname.lname;


$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Username: $uname \n Email Address: $email \n Amount: $amount \n  Facebook link: $link \n Account details: $acct \n";
$recipient = "withdrawal@plantfunds.com";
$subject = "Withdrawal Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Your withdrawal request has been submitted successfully and you have been debited instantly, please kindly wait for moderation";
            
  
    }
}else{

echo '<form method="POST" action="https://plantfunds.com/withdrawal/">
                <label for="uname">Username:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" required=" "><br>

            <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required=" "><br>

            <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required=" "><br>

            <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required=" "><br>

            <label for="acct">Bank Details:</label><br>
                <textarea id="email" name="acct" required=" "> </textarea>  <br>


                <label for="amount">Amount to withdraw:</label><br>
                <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" value="amount" required=" "><br><br>

            <label for="link">Facebook link:</label><br>

            <input type="url" id="link" name="link" required=" "><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Request">
            </form>';
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) in your plugin or theme or, if you don't want to add a plugin or modify the theme, use [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin. Your code will look like this:

```
add_shortcode( "your-awesome-unique-shortcode", "wpse376442_your_awesome_shortcode_callback");

function wpse376442_your_awesome_shortcode_callback($atts, $content, $shortcode_tag) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id );
    $echo = "Current Balance: ".$balance."<br><br>";
    if ($_POST && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['amount'])){
        $towithdraw = $_POST['amount'];
            $towithdraws = "-".$towithdraw;
            if ($towithdraw > $balance){
                $echo = "Insufficient Funds!";
        }else{
            mycred_subtract( 'Withdrawal', $user_id, $towithdraws, 'Activity earnings withdrawal' );
    
            $uname = $_POST['uname'];
            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            $acct = $_POST['acct'];
            $link = $_POST['link'];
            
            $name = $fname.lname;
            
            
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $formcontent=" From: $name \n Username: $uname \n Email Address: $email \n Amount: $amount \n  Facebook link: $link \n Account details: $acct \n";
            $recipient = "withdrawal@plantfunds.com";
            $subject = "Withdrawal Form";
            $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
            
            wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
            
            $echo = "Your withdrawal request has been submitted successfully and you have been debited instantly, please kindly wait for moderation";
                
      
        }
    }else {
    
        $echo = '<form method="POST" action="https://plantfunds.com/withdrawal/">
                    <label for="uname">Username:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" required=" "><br>
    
                <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required=" "><br>
    
                <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" required=" "><br>
    
                <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required=" "><br>
    
                <label for="acct">Bank Details:</label><br>
                    <textarea id="email" name="acct" required=" "> </textarea>  <br>
    
    
                    <label for="amount">Amount to withdraw:</label><br>
                    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" value="amount" required=" "><br><br>
    
                <label for="link">Facebook link:</label><br>
    
                <input type="url" id="link" name="link" required=" "><br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Request">
                </form>';
    }
    return $echo;
}
```

Note that I converted the echo's to strings and returned them. As the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#more-information) says:

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an
> output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is
> to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly
> will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but it's no longer getting user current balance which is necessary. Please any other suggestions?

Comment: @OnyekaFranklin Is it showing "Current Balance:" part?  If yes, try to print $user_id instead and let me what you see. Of course, make sure you're logged in.

Comment: its not showing user current balance and i am logged in

Comment: Is it showing the user id? Could you post the whole code somewhere so we can see it?